# Invited user Azure Devops project but they are unable to access it

Tags: azure-devops

I added a user to my Azure Devops project but when they click on the link in the invitation email they get the "401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access." error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please specify if the user has acces to another Azure Devops. If the user has Azure account, which type of accout (corporate Azure AD or own).

Comment: What I did that seems to have worked, was I made the project public, and the other user was able to access it. After they had accessed one time successfully I made it private again. They are still able to get to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps '401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access' Invited User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202630/azure-devops-401-uh-oh-you-do-not-have-access-invited-user)

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your **Azure DevOps organization is AAD based or not**. Then that invited user should use corresponding account, work/school account for AAD based, personal account for the other. For example:

[image]

A highly specific 401 error case. In this case, both a personal Microsoft account and a work or school account (Azure AD) that have the same sign-in address exist. You've signed in with your work or school account, but your personal account is the identity with access to the organization.

More detail explanation you could take a look at our official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-configure-customize-organization?view=azure-devops#q-whats-the-difference-between-using-a-microsoft-account-and-a-work-account-or-school-account-to-sign-up):

> *Why can't I sign in after I select "personal Microsoft account" or
>   "work or school account"?*
>
> Although both identities use the same sign-in address, they're separate: they have different profiles, security settings, and permissions. Sign out completely from Azure DevOps by completing the following steps. Closing your browser might not sign you out
>    completely. Sign in again and select your other identity:
>
> 1. Close all browsers, including browsers that aren't running Azure DevOps.
> 2. Open a private or incognito browsing session.
> 3. Go to this URL: https://aka.ms/vssignout.
>
> You see a message that says, "Sign out in progress." After you sign out, you're redirected to the Azure DevOps @dev.azure.microsoft.com webpage.
>
> If the sign-out page takes more than a minute to sign you out, close the browser and continue.
>
> 4. Sign in to Azure DevOps again. Select your other identity.

Suggest you to use a InPrivate mode browser to login, then use your Microsoft Account to authenticate, also select personal account if you need to choose between a "work or school account" and my "personal account".

Answer (score 0):

What I did that seems to have worked, was I made the project public, and the other user was able to access it. After they had accessed one time successfully I made it private again. They are still able to get to it.