# issues with Azure DevOps Organization permission issue- Error 401

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i am trying to deploy code in Azure DevOps with GitHub. The issue is that i cannot bring the rest of my team in my Organization and Project, despite me adding them as organization & project members. they receive emails but when logging in they receive an error 401. Tried to see if anyone else has encountered the same issue but unfortunately I cannot find anything similar. This might be a basic issue but its big enough to annoy me so far.

> **401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.** 
> Your account, b******@gmail.com is not authorized to view this page. Make sure the URL is > > correct and your account has access. View a list of your organizations here. You may request > access by contacting the admin. 
> 11/27/2020 9:14:41 AM (UTC)

I tried to find the right tags, unfortunately, I am not famous enough for stackoverflow to trust me with creating a specific tag ‍♂️

thanks,

Comment: Visit in a browser in private mode, if you can access, then switch to your original browser, refresh the browser, then you should be able to access now. So the Carl Zhao`s answer should be correct, please check if works for you, let me know for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a new incognito window and sign in to your organization : `https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}` with the invited account in this incognito window. see: [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-configure-customize-organization?view=azure-devops#q-why-cant-i-sign-in-after-i-select-personal-microsoft-account-or-work-or-school-account).

1.Close all browsers, including browsers that aren't running Azure DevOps.

2.Open a private or incognito browsing session.

3.Go to this URL: `https://aka.ms/vssignout`.

You see a message that says, "Sign out in progress." After you sign out, you're redirected to the Azure DevOps @dev.azure.microsoft.com webpage.

4.Sign in to Azure DevOps again. Select your other identity.

Similar problem：[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202630/azure-devops-401-uh-oh-you-do-not-have-access-invited-user).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)