How do I resolve the "401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access. The request requires authentication." error when I try to join client devops organization?
I received an email from a client organization where they are inviting me to join their devops organization with my existing work email associated with a company different from the client. My work email is already used to sign into the work company devops organization. But, apparently I get the "401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access. The request requires authentication." error after trying to sign into the client devops organization.
I tried accepting the invitation and join sometime between 12 and 24 hours after receiving the invitation email. I'm not sure if the time limit for the invitation link was 12 hours or not? I wonder if that might be the cause, but I'm not sure. Before trying to join, I did remove the guest client organization account from my list of organizations because I thought maybe the already existing guest account might cause problems trying to re-setup multi-factor authentication with client devops account on a different phone.  But, maybe that made the problem worse? I would appreciate any help on figuring out what the root cause is?

Did you take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202630/azure-devops-401-uh-oh-you-do-not-have-access-invited-user ? If the steps here help, e.g. using incognito and signing in again?
